# Why does the Optional isPresent class method take Consumer<? super T> as a parameter, not Consumer<T>?

Tags: java, generics

I'm reading about wildcard and I'm a little confused.I don't really understand why the ifPresent method needs `? super T` .
`public void ifPresent(Consumer<? super T> consumer)`
Why doesn't just T work?

I've read about PECS and it's clear how it works for class methods, for example,but why is it here in the interface, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Well, you'd want to be able to pass a consumer that only can work on a super type of `T` as well, e.g. if you'd have a consumer that only accepts `CharSequence` which you'd want to pass to a `Optional<String>`. If the signature was `Consumer<T>` you'd not be able to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely reason is to allow `Consumer`s of a type broader than `T` (which is a type that is compatible with `T`) to be able to be used for the `consumer` argument.

Here's an example:

```
Optional<String> opt = Optional.of("abc");
Optional<Integer> intOptional = Optional.of(2);

Consumer<Object> printConsumer = System.out::println;
opt.ifPresent(printConsumer);
intOptional.ifPresent(printConsumer);
```

`printConsumer` is just a function that prints objects. So it works with both `String` and `Integer` types.

If `ifPresent` took only `Consumer<T>`, one would not be able to write code as the above, because one can't use `Consumer<Object>` where `Consumer<String>` or `Consumer<Integer>` is required. But in cases where a consumer instance already exists and is compatible with multiple `T` types, `Consumer<? super T>` makes it possible to reuse the consumer instance.